# Adding values if characters match in list

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to sum the occurrence of every possible letter in a character string in a list but if I do:

```
table(simplify2array(as.vector(x)))
Error in base::table(...) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

So I did the following and made a table for each character string.

```
x <- lapply(x, table) 
head(lapply(x, table))

[[1]]

E F G H L N P Q R S Y 
1 2 1 2 3 1 1 3 3 2 1 

[[2]]

A C D G I K L N P R V 
1 1 2 1 1 3 2 4 3 1 1
```

How can I now add up all of these values if the letters exist in each list? Each list can have different letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybee you could use:

```
x_v <- unlist(x)
table(x_v)
```

if this dosn't work. The `aggregate()` command could help you.